# After iOS 12 to 13 upgrade, Photos.app corrupts large .MOV files

Tags: ios, video

I have an iPhone 8. I recently upgraded from iOS 12.4.1 (if I recall correctly) to iOS 13.3.

The very first time I tried to scrape the photos off my iPhone 8 onto my MacBook Pro, it hung. The Apple Photos.app process was using very little CPU, it was using very little I/O (it should basically be maxing it out), and it was making no progress.

I soon realized that it hangs if the "new batch" of photos contains a .MOV file that is "sufficiently large", but that is about ONE MINUTE.

Not only do I need to force-quit, but the .MOV file is corrupted. I didn't realize because I don't usually watch them, or not that soon. It is not badly corrupted, they play in VLC, but they don't play in Photos.app.

So it will get to one .MOV file, use up all the disk space, and produce a slightly borked .MOV file. Then helpfully delete the original.

The stupidest possible work-around is to put the longer videos in a separate "album", the way that iOS 13 added an album for screenshots (which annoys me, they should all be "camera roll").

Another stupid work-around that works with iOS 13 but not iOS 12 is to use AirDrop for large videos. Which shows how they are spending the money.

I'm curious if other people have this problem. The photos scheme changed a lot, and I am not surprised.